# remove advance duplicate records (distinct in more than one columns in dataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe, math

I want to remove the duplicated values in my `pandas` dataFrame.

my DataFram is like this:

```
#  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
1    a      a      1      1    # unwanted
2    a      b     0.7    0.5
3    a      c     0.5    0.3
4    b      a     0.7    0.5   # Duplicated
5    b      b      1      1    # unwanted
6    b      c     0.8    0.6
7    c      a     0.5    0.3   # Duplicated
8    c      b     0.8    0.6   # Duplicated
9    c      c      1      1    # unwanted
```

How we can improve this DataFrame and remove unwanted and duplicated rows?

may you think that this data frame is like a squared matrix and we can use `np.tril` but now it's not that

cus we need to calculate the rank of `col_3` and `col_4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case do `np.sort` then `drop_duplicates`

```
df[['col_1','col_2']] = np.sort(df[['col_1','col_2']].values,axis=1)
out = df.drop_duplicates(['col_1','col_2']).query('col_1!=col_2')
out
Out[118]: 
  col_1 col_2  col_3  col_4
2     a     b    0.7    0.5
3     a     c    0.5    0.3
6     b     c    0.8    0.6
```

Comment: Thanks you for your great answer, but now i want to prevent generate this duplicates in for loop! how can i prevent generate j,i by add condition on list ?

Answer (score 0):

[.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset =['col1', 'col2],
                     keep = False, inplace = True)
```